# Javascript Quintus Endless Runner NAN error

Tags: javascript

I've come across a problem that I've never seen before as I'm fairly new to javascript. Currently trying to get a HUD working on an endless runner game I've downloaded (link: http://www.html5quintus.com/quintus/examples/runner/). Have copied all the images, JSON, javascript and index files and have managed to get it working with some gui labels along the top of the screen to indicate the number of lives and health remaining. Upon a collision of the player with a crate, I'm deducting 25 (stored in a variable called hitAmount) from the overall health of the player (starts at 100), however - upon the first impact between the player and a crate, I see 'NAN' rather than a result of a simple subtraction calculation. Does anyone know why this is the case?

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {

var Q = window.Q = Quintus()
        .include("Sprites, Scenes, Input, 2D, Anim, Touch, UI")
        .setup({ maximize: true })
        .controls().touch()

var SPRITE_BOX = 1;
Q.gravityY = 2000;
var lives = 3;
var damageAmount = 25;

Q.Sprite.extend("Player",{

  init: function(p) {

    this._super(p,{
      sheet: "player",
      sprite: "player",
      collisionMask: SPRITE_BOX, 
      x: 40,
      y: 555,
      standingPoints: [ [ -16, 44], [ -23, 35 ], [-23,-48], [23,-48], [23, 35 ], [ 16, 44 ]],
      duckingPoints : [ [ -16, 44], [ -23, 35 ], [-23,-10], [23,-10], [23, 35 ], [ 16, 44 ]],
      speed: 500,
      health: 100,
      jump: -700
    });

    this.p.points = this.p.standingPoints;
    this.add("2d, animation");
  },

  step: function(dt) {
    this.p.vx += (this.p.speed - this.p.vx)/4;

    if(this.p.y > 555) {
      this.p.y = 555;
      this.p.landed = 1;
      this.p.vy = 0;
    } else {
      this.p.landed = 0;
    }

    if(Q.inputs['up'] && this.p.landed > 0) {
      this.p.vy = this.p.jump;
    } 

    this.p.points = this.p.standingPoints;
    if(this.p.landed) {
      if(Q.inputs['down']) { 
        this.play("duck_right");
        this.p.points = this.p.duckingPoints;
      } else {
        this.play("walk_right");
      }
    } else {
      this.play("jump_right");
    }

    this.stage.viewport.centerOn(this.p.x + 300, 400 );

  }
});

Q.Sprite.extend("Box",{
  init: function() {

    var levels = [ 565, 540, 500, 450 ];

    var player = Q("Player").first();
    this._super({
      x: player.p.x + Q.width + 50,
      y: levels[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)],
      frame: Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 0,
      scale: 2,
      type: SPRITE_BOX,
      sheet: "crates",
      vx: -600 + 200 * Math.random(),
      vy: 0,
      ay: 0,
      theta: (300 * Math.random() + 200) * (Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1)
    });


    this.on("hit");
  },

  step: function(dt) {
    this.p.x += this.p.vx * dt;


    this.p.vy += this.p.ay * dt;
    this.p.y += this.p.vy * dt;
    if(this.p.y != 565) {
      this.p.angle += this.p.theta * dt;
    }

    if(this.p.y > 800) { this.destroy(); }

  },

  hit: function() { 
    this.p.type = 0;
    this.p.collisionMask = Q.SPRITE_NONE;
    this.p.vx = 200;
    this.p.ay = 400;
    this.p.vy = -300;
    this.p.opacity = 0.5;
    //change this so crate hitting player reduces his health
    parseInt(this.p.health -= damageAmount);
    Q.stageScene('hud', 3, this.p);
  }
});

Q.GameObject.extend("BoxThrower",{
  init: function() {
    this.p = {
      launchDelay: 0.75,
      launchRandom: 1,
      launch: 2
    }
  },

  update: function(dt) {
    this.p.launch -= dt;

    if(this.p.launch < 0) {
      this.stage.insert(new Q.Box());
      this.p.launch = this.p.launchDelay + this.p.launchRandom * Math.random();
    }
  }

});


Q.scene("level1",function(stage) {

  stage.insert(new Q.Repeater({ asset: "background-wall.png",
                                speedX: 0.5 }));

  stage.insert(new Q.Repeater({ asset: "background-floor.png",
                                repeatY: false,
                                speedX: 1.0,
                                y: 300 }));

  stage.insert(new Q.BoxThrower());
  stage.insert(new Q.Player());
  stage.add("viewport");

});

Q.scene('hud',function(stage) {
  var container = stage.insert(new Q.UI.Container({
    x: 50, y: 0
  }));

  var label = container.insert(new Q.UI.Text({x:200, y: 20,
    label: "health: " + stage.options.health, color: "Fuchsia" }));

  var strength = container.insert(new Q.UI.Text({x:50, y: 20,
    label: "Lives: " + lives, color: "Fuchsia" }));

  container.fit(20);
});

Q.load("player.json, player.png, background-wall.png, background-floor.png, crates.png, crates.json", function() {
    Q.compileSheets("player.png","player.json");
    Q.compileSheets("crates.png","crates.json");
    Q.animations("player", {
      walk_right: { frames: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], rate: 1/15, flip: false, loop: true },
      jump_right: { frames: [13], rate: 1/10, flip: false },
      stand_right: { frames:[14], rate: 1/10, flip: false },
      duck_right: { frames: [15], rate: 1/10, flip: false },
    });
    Q.stageScene("level1");
    Q.stageScene('hud', 3, Q('Player').first().p);
});

});
```

Comment: console.log the values prior to the deduction, one will not be numeric, trace back and figure out why

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - Many thanks to Alex K for the suggestion. Created another variable to store the health value upon initialisation and then fed this into the subtraction calculation. Now updating as it should.